# Where mongoose execute the queries?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to understand better how mongoose work.

I have nodejs in serverA and mongodb in serverB.

When I run `.find(..)` or any others mongoose function, Did they run on serverB and return the result using `tcp` to my nodejs application? or ask for serverB to get all the rows and then in serverA is run the functions?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose only transforms your object oriented code into various MongoDB queries. The queries are always run on the server - the database engine will do the computations and the Node.js client will receive the ready made results. Mongoose (serverA) tries to optimise most of the queries (like classic relational database ORMs) and offload CPU expensive tasks to MongoDB (server B) - sorting, filtering, aggregations etc. As long as you specify the logic you want to execute in your queries and do not run client-side filtering/sorting, you shouldn't be worried that your Node.js main thread will get blocked by CPU intensive tasks.